# Reduce size of VMWare virtual machine

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I am running VMWare Fusion 3.1.2 on Mac with a Windows 7 virtual machine. The size of the virtual machine file continually grows no matter how much data I have on there. It is currently at 109 GB. I just threw out 3 GB of files but the size of the VM stayed the same. Will this VM just grow and grow? I will soon reach a point where I can not longer host it on my Mac or back it up.

Comment: Do you have snapshots of the guest?

Comment: yes fergNab and I did not realize they took up so much space. How many snapshots is responsible to maintain?

Answer (score 1):

Try performing a disk cleanup. Enter the virtual machine’s settings and go to Hard Disks -> Clean Up Disk.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time since this was asked, but 109GB is a huge size.  It sounds as if snapshots are being used and if so, see http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1025279 and http://bulldogdata.com/2012/08/why-vmware-snapshots-are-both-good-and-really-really-bad/ for advice on how many to keep (few and for a short time, basically).